# after refresh, no comment shows

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

When I add a comment, it Shows for the first time. and if the page refreshed, there will be no comment. It means that if a page has comment it doesn't show until the next comment add.

```
Get Comments method in service:


`public Tuple<List<ChallangeComment>, int> GetChallangeComment(int ChallangeId, int pageId = 1)
        {
            return Tuple.Create(_context.ChallangeComment.Include(c=>c.User)
                .Where(c => !c.IsDelete && c.ChallangeID == ChallangeId)
                .Skip(skip)
                .Take(take)
                .OrderByDescending(c=>c.CreateDate)
                .ToList(),pageCount);
        }`


Controller:


`
public IActionResult CreateComment(ChallangeComment comment)
        {
            comment.UserID = _userService.GetUserIdByUserName(User.Identity.Name);
            _challangeService.AddComment(comment);

            return View("ShowComment",_challangeService.GetChallangeComment(comment.ChallangeID));
        }

        public IActionResult ShowComment(int challangeId,int pageId=1)
        {
            return View(_challangeService.GetChallangeComment(challangeId, pageId));
        }`



View:

`<textarea required class="form-control" id="comment_Comment" name="comment.Comment" rows="8"></textarea>
 </div>

<div class="review" id="listComment"></div>

@section scripts{
    <script src="~/assets/js/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>
    
    <script>
    function Success() {
        $('#comment_Comment').val("");
    }

    $(function () {
        $('#listComment').load("/Challange/ShowComment/" +@Model.ChallangeID);
    });
    </script>
}`
```

help please.. where's the problem? :(

Comment: More details is required to reproduce the issue

Comment: $('#listComment').load("/Challange/ShowComment/" +@Model.ChallangeID)  why you load the page itself again?